# Android Rss feed from facebook page

Tags: android, rss

The data is received and is shown on the log. However I can't seem to display it on the screen. It keeps saying java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. However I tried exactly these lines in another project and seems to be working fine.

Here is the code many thanks in advance:

MainActivity.java

```
package synctc.me.rssfeed;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 private Current mCurrent ;
  @InjectView(R.id.title)TextView mTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getUrl();
        Log.d(TAG,"Main UI is Running");
    }

 private void getUrl(){
     String url ="https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=311612925545909";
     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
     Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url(url)
             .build();
     Call call=client.newCall(request);
     call.enqueue(new Callback() {
         @Override
         public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                 }
             });

         }

         @Override
         public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {

                 }
             });
             try {
                 String jsonData = response.body().string();
                 Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                 if(response.isSuccessful()){
                     mCurrent = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             updateDisplay();
                         }
                     });

                 }else{

                 }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught : ",e);

             }
             catch (JSONException e){

                 Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught : ",e);
             }

         }
     });}



private  void updateDisplay (){
    mTitle.setText(mCurrent.getTitle()+"");


}

    private Current getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject channel = new JSONObject (jsonData);
        String channelVal = channel.getString("channel");
        JSONObject currently = new JSONObject(channel.get("channel").toString());
        Current current = new Current();
        current.setTitle(currently.getString("title"));
        Log.i(TAG,"From JSON To:"+channelVal);
        return  current;
    }
}
```

Current.java

```
public class Current {

 private String  mChannel;
 private String mTitle;
 private String mDescription;
 private String mImg;


    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        mDescription = description;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return mImg;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        mImg = img;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return mChannel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        mChannel = channel;
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
 <rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    >
    <channel>
    <title>حائط ‏‎Professional Hackers‎‏ على فيسبوك</title>
    <link>https://www.facebook.com/</link>
    <description>حائط ‏‎Professional Hackers‎‏ على فيسبوك</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <category domain="Facebook">PageSyndicationFeed</category>
    <generator>Facebook Syndication</generator><docs>http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification</docs>
    <lastBuildDate>Mon, 08 Sep 2014 10:48:32 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <webMaster>webmaster@facebook.com</webMaster>
    <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">www.facebook.com/notification/847a02dda3e67da1443312712cc478b4</guid>
    <title><![CDATA[ ]]></title>
    <link>http://www.facebook.com/ProfessionalHackers00/photos/a.342883082418893.81113.311612925545909/825529307487599/?type=1</link>
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="/ProfessionalHackers00/photos/a.342883082418893.81113.311612925545909/825529307487599/?type=1&amp;relevant_count=1" id="" title="" target="" onclick="" style=""><img class="img" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-g.ak/hphotos-ak-xta1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/10665141_825529307487599_4548128653985487900_n.png?oh=6469cb21ce0091796b296364f61232fa&amp;oe=55AB5930&amp;__gda__=1436725829_d9cda3c297f41ce6485f644c528b429e" alt="" /></a><br/>]]></description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 08 Sep 2014 11:48:32 +0100</pubDate>
    <author>‪Professional Hackers‬</author>
    <dc:creator>‪Professional Hackers‬</dc:creator>
    </item>
    <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">www.facebook.com/notification/d22710b9bde130cf6d5efda7d4256f7e</guid>
    <title><![CDATA[ Tired of Blocked Websites?  !! This trick will surely help you
    Top methods to...]]></title>
    <link>http://www.facebook.com/ProfessionalHackers00/posts/825529050820958</link>
    <description><![CDATA[‪Tired of Blocked Websites?  !! This trick will surely help you <br /> <br /> Top methods to open / access blocked sites without PROXY <br /> <br /> Visit: ‬<a href="http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FVL0Hb9&amp;h=GAQGfLVzP&amp;s=1" rel="nofollow nofollow" target="_blank" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/goo.gl\/VL0Hb9&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/l.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fgoo.gl\u00252FVL0Hb9&amp;h=GAQGfLVzP&amp;s=1&quot;);">http://goo.gl/VL0Hb9</a>‪<br /> ‬<br/><br/><a href="http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FVL0Hb9&amp;h=cAQG3TXIB&amp;s=1" id="" title="" target="" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/l.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fgoo.gl\u00252FVL0Hb9&amp;h=cAQG3TXIB&amp;s=1&quot;);" style="" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/goo.gl\/VL0Hb9&quot;);"><img class="img" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/external.ak/safe_image.php?d=AQCqiahUKnLbcfwh&amp;w=158&amp;h=158&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-a-vie.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xpf1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2F10603264_825528994154297_1736307390360087029_n.png%3Foh%3Dc48a5971b5dfc19555267662e13c219a%26oe%3D54949E9D" alt="" /></a><br/><a href="http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FVL0Hb9&amp;h=WAQFr5mbg&amp;s=1" id="" target="_blank" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/l.facebook.com\/l.php?u=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fgoo.gl\u00252FVL0Hb9&amp;h=WAQFr5mbg&amp;s=1&quot;);" style="" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;http:\/\/goo.gl\/VL0Hb9&quot;);">‪Top methods to open / access blocked sites without PROXY | Cool Tips and Tricks‬</a><br/>www.gotipsandtrick.info]]></description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 08 Sep 2014 11:47:17 +0100</pubDate>
    <author>‪Professional Hackers‬</author>
    <dc:creator>‪Professional Hackers‬</dc:creator>
    </item>
    <item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">www.facebook.com/notification/d5aa50993c46015a9af
04-08 07:29:00.338    1875-1893/synctc.me.rssfeed E/MainActivity﹕ Exception Caught :
    org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
            at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
            at synctc.me.rssfeed.MainActivity.getCurrentDetails(MainActivity.java:105)
            at synctc.me.rssfeed.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:27)
            at synctc.me.rssfeed.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:73)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Improved readability

Answer (score 0):

The response you get by accessing the facebook link is in XML format.

When the parser tries to read your document, it tries converting

> ?xml

into a json